# Display max values for multiple groups based on previous COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, max

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT Takes_T.sec_id AS 'Section ID',
Takes_T.semester AS 'Semester',
Takes_T.year AS 'Year',
COUNT(Takes_T.takes_id) AS 'Enrollment'


From Takes_T

Group By Takes_T.year, Takes_T.semester, Takes_T.sec_id
ORDER BY Takes_T.year, Takes_T.semester DESC, Takes_T.sec_id,
Takes_T.course_id

;
```

This produces the following results:
(I apologize for the crappy formatting. I could not figure out how to get this in a table)

```
Section ID | Semester | Year | Enrollment
     1     | Spring   | 2014 | 12922
     2     | Spring   | 2014 |  1434
     3     | Spring   | 2014 |   322
     1     | Fall     | 2014 | 12590
     2     | Fall     | 2014 |  2732
```

What I need to do is display the MAX enrollment for each section (a section is the combination of Section ID, Semester, and Year). So what I need is:

```
Section ID  Semester   Year    Enrollment
    1       Spring     2014      12922
    1        Fall      2014      12590
```

How do I modify my query to display just the MAX for each section?

Comment: But your section id is different for semester and year so how can it be unique?

Comment: The instructor had us use a composite primary key of Section ID, Semester, and Year. The combination keeps them unique. I am not saying I like that necessarily, but it was dictated by the instructor.

Comment: The result you give does not correspond to your question. If Section ID is part of the key, then `2 Spring 2014` is different section than `1 Spring 2014`. Why would you include only the latter in the results and not the former?

Comment: You are correct that 2 Spring 2014 is different than 1 Spring 2014. The reason only 1 Spring 2014 shows up in the latter results is that the instructor only wants the maximum enrollment for each section. In this case 1 Spring 2014 has the maximum enrollment (12922), so that is the only line that should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which RDBMS you're using, but the following should work with MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    sec_id AS 'Section ID',
    semester AS 'Semester',
    year AS 'Year',
    COUNT(takes_id) AS 'Enrollment'
FROM Takes_T t
WHERE sec_id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 sec_id
    FROM Takes_T
    WHERE year = t.year
    AND semester = t.semester
    GROUP BY year, semester
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
)
GROUP BY year, semester, sec_id
ORDER BY year, semester DESC, sec_id
```

**EDIT**: here's the same for MySQL:

```
SELECT
    sec_id AS 'Section ID',
    semester AS 'Semester',
    year AS 'Year',
    COUNT(takes_id) AS 'Enrollment'
FROM Takes_T t
WHERE sec_id = (
    SELECT sec_id
    FROM Takes_T
    WHERE year = t.year
    AND semester = t.semester
    GROUP BY year, semester
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
GROUP BY year, semester, sec_id
ORDER BY year, semester DESC, sec_id
```

Comment: My apologies. I am using MySQL. When I enter that into the query window, I get a syntax error. "Unexpected TOP' in line 8.

Comment: I am attempting to run the query as you designed it, but I never get any results. The RDBMS just keeps processing. I cancelled the first time after 129 seconds and the second after 194. Now I am just letting it run, but nothing yet. Would this technique you proposed be especially taxing to process?

Comment: It depends on the design of the table, how the indexes are defined.  How long did the original query take to run?  How many rows in total on the table?  Defining an index on year, semester would be useful if there isn't one already.

Comment: The original query executes very quickly, usually less than a few seconds. The DB has roughly 33K records. I let your query run as posted for as long as 288 seconds, and another time I let it run until the DB finally dropped me. I am not sure how to define an index, so I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a nested select:

```
SELECT max(Enrollment), SectionId, Semester, Year 
FROM
(SELECT 
   Takes_T.sec_id AS 'SectionID',
   Takes_T.semester AS 'Semester',
   Takes_T.year AS 'Year',
   COUNT(Takes_T.takes_id) AS 'Enrollment'
FROM Takes_T
GROUP BY Takes_T.year, Takes_T.semester, Takes_T.sec_id) a
GROUP BY SectionId, Semester, Year
```

Comment: Thank you, but that query actually produces the same results as my original query, but the columns are in different order.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the code I used:

```
SELECT Semester,
Year,
MIN(Enrollment) AS 'Min Enrollment',
MAX(Enrollment) AS 'Max Enrollment' 

FROM(
SELECT Takes_T.sec_id AS 'Section_ID',
Takes_T.semester AS 'Semester',
Takes_T.year AS 'Year',
COUNT(Takes_T.takes_id) AS 'Enrollment'


From Takes_T

Group By Takes_T.year, Takes_T.semester, Takes_T.sec_id) MaxE
GROUP BY Year, Semester
ORDER BY Semester DESC
;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would work to me.  You shouldn't be able to include a column (Section_ID) in the SELECT that isn't in the GROUP BY, which only has Year and Semester.  Your example suggested that you needed to know which Section_ID has the greatest enrollment - is this correct?

Comment: Looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html it appears that MySQL allows nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause, so the above query will run, but will probably NOT give you the correct results, except by coincidence. Quote: "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate." - so your Section_ID column will not give you any reliable information.

Comment: I think the confusion is because terms are reused. The problem is to find the maximum enrollment across all sections (not the same as Section_ID). A section is the combination of year, semester, and section_id. In Spring 2014 there are 3 sections. I need to identify which section_id within that time period (Spring 2014) has the maximum enrollment. In this case it is section 1. I then need to do the same thing for Fall 2014. Does that make sense?

Comment: We commented at about the same time, so I'm not sure which comment of mine you're replying to.  I understand what you need, but I don't believe your query will work.  It will give you the correct max enroillment figure, but it will just pick any old Section_ID (probably the first one, which just happens to be correct).  You can check by querying for MIN instead of MAX, I bet the Section_ID won't change.

Comment: You are correct. When changing to MIN, the value of section_id does not change. The enrollment values appear to be correct when performing this with either MIN or MAX, but the section_id is wrong. If I can get that figured out, I am good. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the answer I posted.  If you answer the comments on there, maybe we can work out why it's taking so long to run.

Comment: It turns out I was making this more difficult than needed. Ultimately I needed to display both the maximum and minimum enrollment for each section. I was trying to get to this end result by first identifying the maximum for each section and then I was going to figure out how to also display the minimum. However, the instructor does not care about seeing the section_id in the results. By removing the requirement of displaying the section_id I was able to display both the max and min for each section with the above query. Thank you to everyone for your help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did the temp table answer I posted provide the correct results?

Comment: I did try that solution, but I got an error saying I am not authorized to create temp tables. It very well might work, but I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you can use temp tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS enrollment_count AS (
    SELECT
        sec_id,
        semester,
        year,
        COUNT(takes_id) AS 'enrollment'
    FROM Takes_T
    GROUP BY year, semester, sec_id
);
SELECT
    sec_id,
    semester,
    year,
    enrollment
FROM enrollment_count ec
WHERE enrollment = (
    SELECT MAX(enrollment)
    FROM enrollment_count sub
    WHERE sub.semester = ec.semester
    AND sub.year = ec.year
)
```